# Using neo4j with ruby

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neography, neo4j.rb

(PLEASE , THIS QUESTION IS ABOUT NEO4J FOR RUBY AND NOT FOR RUBY ON RAILS)

I would like to develop a small database driven application using ruby and neo4j ,my question is about the deployment part , so , persons who will use the app will have to install neo4j first in their computers or can i package it with the app at once ?

Any help would be appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application will need a database to communicate with. You'll either need to host one for them or they will need to have one locally. Neo4j does not support multitenancy so unless you can enforce separation of client data at an app level, you will need a separate instance of the database for each client, should you choose to host it for them.

Answer (score 0):

To ease installing your app as a gem, I'd suggest to include the [neo4j-rake-tasks](https://rubygems.org/gems/neo4j-rake_tasks) into your projects. Users can then call `rake neo4j:install` and `rake neo4j:start` to setup a database.

However, your application should ship with a config file to allow users setting up their own database (for instance in a cloud environment).

Have a look at this: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-cloud-deployment/

Rumor has it there's an official Neo4j cloud service coming up soon.